# chrome extension download API is slow to respond and doesn't change the filename

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using chrome messaging feature to send the filename and link to the background page

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({link: thelink, name:filename}, function(response) {});
```

The background.js

```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(message.name);
            chrome.downloads.download({
                                url: message.link,
                                filename: message.name,
                                conflictAction: 'prompt'
                            });

        });
```

My manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "4ch",
    "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "4ch-icon-16.png", "48": "4ch-icon-48.png", "128": "4ch-icon-48.png"
    }
    ,
    "permissions": ["downloads",
    "<all_urls>",
    "contextMenus"],
    "content_scripts": [{

      "js": ["script/jquery.js", "script/reddit.js"],
       "matches": ["*://*.reddit.com/*"]  
    }


    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["script/jquery.js","script/eventpage.js"], "persistent": false
    }
}
```

the download only starts after a few seconds and doesn't change the file name

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine for me. Needs more context. If there's a delay, it's probably in your content script before you invoke `sendMessage` or something. If you inspect the background page, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Does it work for you? I just tried in the background page console with with a link and a file name. And the file doesn't have the name that I have given

Comment: Yup. Running this in my extension's background page works just fine : `chrome.downloads.download({ url: "http://thecatapi.com/?id=cco", filename: "g.png", conflictAction: 'prompt' });` I also did a full test using `runtime` like in your question and that's fine too. So we need more info on your context.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. My extension is in conflict is in conflict with 'chrome download Master' extension It works when I disable it

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, you need to [edit] your question to contain enough information such that someone else could figure out the answer (e.g. add a full [MCVE] and specifically state that you are using the extension which you found to be conflicting).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have ofund a solution. The 'download master' extension was in conflict with my own,hence it doesn't replace the original filename.I have disabled it